# how to put a text field on top of google maps iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

My goal is to put a text field on top of google maps iOS but seems like it doesn't work

[image]

When I run the app, the text field doesn't exist on top of Google Maps

[image]

The code

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20)
        marker.title = "Sydney"
        marker.snippet = "Australia"
        marker.map = mapView

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: chnage the view hierachy -- > textfield --> googlemap or use your textfield bringtofront

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the super easy solution to do the same with `storyboard`.

**Add Constraints**

*Note : if you have issues to view GIF, please download and separate frame*

[image]

**Output**

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding `UITextField` as `subView` of `MapView`, add both in a same `UIView` & just put the `UITextfield` over `MApView`. Change it like this

Comment: Im super confused, I tried to reorganize my text field but seems like it doesn't work